# Datetime issue with PHP 7.4 when doing json_encode (I am using Carbon)

Tags: php, datetime, php-carbon, php-7.4

I have upgraded PHP from 7.0 to 7.4 and my code doesn't behave the same when I put a datatime in a json_encode.
I've seen this issue in PHP bugs but I don't know how to fix it.
[Bugs.php bug 78383](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=78383)

now if I do json_decode with a datetime I get a void array [] of the date.

For this code:

```
$dataTest['text'] = "some text for the example";
$dataTest['date'] = Carbon::now();
$dateEncode = json_encode($dataTest);
$dateDecode = json_decode($dateEncode, TRUE);
dd($dataTest, $dateEncode, $dateDecode);
```

I get:

```
array:2 [▼
  "text" => "some text for the example"
  "date" => Carbon {#905 ▼
    +"date": "2021-04-14 10:03:28.736535"
    +"timezone_type": 3
    +"timezone": "Europe/Madrid"
  }
]
"{"text":"some text for the example","date":[]}"
array:2 [▼
  "text" => "some text for the example"
  "date" => []
]
```

I can force Carbon to be a array before the json_encode but its a lot of work to fix all my code
For this code:

```
$dataTest['text'] = "some text for the example";
$dataTest['date'] = (array)Carbon::now();
$dateEncodeArray = json_encode($dataTest);
$dateDecodeArray = json_decode($dateEncodeArray, TRUE);
dd($dateEncodeArray, $dateDecodeArray );
```

I get:

```
"{"text":"some text for the example","date":{"date":"2021-04-14 10:09:32.481792","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Europe\/Madrid"}}"
array:2 [▼
  "text" => "some text for the example"
  "date" => array:3 [▼
    "date" => "2021-04-14 10:09:32.481792"
    "timezone_type" => 3
    "timezone" => "Europe/Madrid"
  ]
]
```

I am using Carbon 1 (nesbot/carbon 1.32.0  A simple API extension for DateTime.)

Someone with the same problem?
Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can customize for Carbon 1 and 2 the way Carbon instance should output in JSON with any format you want:

```
Carbon::serializeUsing(function ($date) {
    return $date->tz('UTC')->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.up');
});

echo json_encode(Carbon::now());
```

This above will give you the same format Carbon 2 would give you by default.

Obviously, you should upgrade, you're 54 minor versions behind, you should handle this at once and it will save you a lot of further trouble being up to date rather than working around incompatibilities to stick in unsupported version.

Comment: Thx, you save my day :D I want update it soon but right now it is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Just update Carbon to a more recent version and you'll be fine:

```sh
$ composer require nesbot/carbon "^2.46"
```

Now you can safely do:

```php
$data = json_decode(json_encode(['date' => Carbon::now()]), true);
```

Dumped, that would give you:

```php
array (

  'date' => '2021-04-14T12:53:04.403585Z',
)
```

If you need to stay with Carbon 1.x for the time being, you could also try to mask Carbon:

```php
use Carbon\Carbon as Charcoal; // Alias Carbon

class Carbon { // Mask original Carbon

    public static function __callStatic($method, $args) {

        // Whatever the given Carbon method returns, cast it to an array
        return (array) Charcoal::{$method}(...$args);  
    }

    // Add more methods as needed 
}
```

Comment: I cannot do that in the short term, there are changes that break code when going from carbon 1 to carbon 2, among them precisely the treatment of Carbon in the jsons. https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-carbon-2

Comment: I've revised my answer to take into account Carbon 1. Masking Carbon (like shown in my answer) should spare you the need of searching & replacing all occurrences of Carbon method calls, though you still would have to alter your `use` declarations to alias Carbon and to reference the replacement class.